# unable to change password at next logon in ubuntu joined on Active directory using PBIS

Tags: 14.04

I have joined ubuntu 14.04 on domin using PBIS. when i check mark on my window server for change password at next login for one user and try to change it , I am unable to do it.

Comment: Type `passwd` in the terminal and enter a new password when asked.

Comment: Actually i have done check mark on window server for  user must change password at next login. i try to change password when login prompt appear in ubuntu. it is not happening.

Comment: I know. That doesn't always work. Just login and type `passwd` in the terminal

Comment: is there no solution for this except changing password from terminal using passwd command. but when password expire i have to change always from AD for all ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.
(it works on Mint, so I suppose it works on Ubuntu too)

You have the issue with GUI, but if you switch to a console tty (example: ctrl-alt-F5) you don't.
at login you'll be asked to change password (and it works)
after that, you need to switch back to GUI (default should be ctrl-alt-f7)

On Mint, I found that with some themes of login manager it works with GUI too (i.e. the "ugly" simple/clean GTK)